# xcode Module 'file_picker' not found

Tags: xcode, flutter

I took over the flutter project

Running android and ios simulators in flutter works fine with no problems

Android version update is no problem

Error in xcode when updating ios version

Error: "Module 'file_picker' not found"
"GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m"

1. flutter doctor -v no problem
2. latest version of file_picker
3. Delete pod and reinstall
4. Run .xcworkspace
5. platform :ios, '11.0' && Deployment info ios 11.0 same

the problem is not solved

Help me